# How can I concatenate, and add dashes to data that needs to be inserted using LOAD DATA IN FILE

Tags: php, concatenation, load-data-infile

Im loading a file straight into a database, to avoid having to process it using PHP.  Because the file contains 2+ million rows.

However, I do still need to "process" the values before inserting.

The file consists of

```
 Col 1 |  Col 2
 200     2505555
```

I can insert this just fine using

```
"LOAD DATA local INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE number_check FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 0 LINES "
```

However....
I want to insert it into only one column.  Concatenated.

```
   Col 1
   2002505555
```

Getting this far would be great.  And might be ok.  But one step further would be even better, if someone knows how.
I basically want to also add dashes and insert it like this

```
   Col 1 
   200-250-5555
```

Is this possible using the LOAD DATA query??
Also ideally, if the column exists, it shouldn't insert it.  Col1 should be a unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured this one out on my own again.  Heres the answer incase anyones interested.

```
SET ID = concat(SUBSTR(`area`, 1, 3), '-', SUBSTR(`number`, 1,3),'-', SUBSTR(`number`,4,7))
```

Or the full query

```
$query = sprintf("LOAD DATA local INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE number_check FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 0 LINES SET ID = concat(SUBSTR(`area`, 1, 3), '-', SUBSTR(`number`, 1,3),'-', SUBSTR(`number`,4,7))", addslashes($file));
```